# How Do You Put Borders Round Cells A to J When The Data Changes In Column F

Tags: vba, excel

Please can you help!

I am trying to put around data when the value is the same in column F which starts in cell F4. I have the boarder coding below but am unsure how to select the data required

My data starts in cell A4 through to column J and varies in length. the data in column F is a 20xx date and I would like to border around A through to J and down to box where the date is the same.

I would then like it to continue down the rest of the report until all dates are bordered

Then add two rows at the bottom with 6 height and the last one is coloured in blue the border should then be put around the whole are that starts from A3 to J varied length.

```
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
```

If anyone can help with this it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you are not using the built-in conditional formatting to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. You may need to modify some of the ranges or your border styles. Let me know how you go with it.

```
Sub borderData()

    Dim dataStartRow As Long
    Dim dataEndRow As Long
    Dim sameDateRowStart As Long, sameDateRowEnd As Long

    sameDateRowStart = 0
    sameDateRowEnd = 0
    dataStartRow = 5
    dataEndRow = Range("A" & dataStartRow).End(xlDown).Row

    '// remove any existing borders
    With Range("A" & dataStartRow & ":J" & dataEndRow)
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    End With

    '// loop through data and border rows with same date
    For i = dataStartRow To dataEndRow + 1
        If Range("F" & i) <> Range("F" & i - 1) Then
            If sameDateRowStart <> 0 And sameDateRowEnd <> 0 Then
                With Range("A" & sameDateRowStart & ":J" & sameDateRowEnd)
                    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                End With
            End If
            sameDateRowStart = i
            sameDateRowEnd = i
        Else
            sameDateRowEnd = i
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend conditional formatting. Although different request, a similar concept is shown 
here in this blog:
http://excel-oh.com/?p=291

Starting in A4, create a new conditional format that looks like this:

```
=left($F4,2)="20"
```

Then apply a border format. After that apply the format accross the entire range. 
You can then apply this to the range.

[image]

Then apply it to the range.